# How to implement rerun on skipped Robot Framework test cases in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, automated-tests, jenkins-pipeline, robotframework, skip

How to implement rerun on failed Robot Framework test cases in jenkins

Failed cases are rerun using below argument declared in the jenkins pipeline, however the dependent cases which were skipped in first run are not picked up on rerun.

rerun_failed: "true",

Only failed cases are executed

Answer (score 0):

Use --rerunfailedsuites instead of --rerunfailed. It should re-run failed test suites including skipped but it will re-run passed test cases as well.